# extract plain text from react object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

somebody knows how could I extract plain text from a react component?

example:

```
const reactObject = 
  <div className="text-primary">
    <span>this is a react object, </span>
    <b>builded with jsx!!!!</b>
  </div>;
.....
//what should I do inside extractText????
const plainText = extractText(reactObject);
alert(reactObject);//result: "[Object object]"
alert(plainText);// must result: "this is a react object builded with jsx!!!!"
```

Comment: `useRef` and `innerText`

Comment: My first question is: why do you want to do this? What's the bigger context?

Comment: If this is inserted in the dom, then you can use getElementsByClassName or a querySelector and then use innerText and it should be built not builded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have write this recursive function if someone needs

```
  extractString(obj) {
    if (typeof obj === 'string') return obj;
    else if (React.isValidElement(obj)) {
      return this.extractString(obj.props.children);
    } else if (Array.isArray(obj)) {
      return obj.map(e => this.extractString(e)).join(' ');
    } else return obj.toString();
  }
```

I'm using this for show error message at bottom of an input:

```
<input ref={.....} value={....} ..... />
<p>{this.props.errorMessage}</p>
```

BUUUUUT if the user still click on the submit button... I want to show the same text in the default browser error message without rewrite setting the same massage only once.

```
const errorMessage = this.extractString(this.props.errorMessage);
//this is the ref to the input
this.input.current.setCustomValidity(errorMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why you need this, but like you were told you in the comments, you can use the `useRef` for your component, and if you know very well the component structure you can get its children and iterate to get the `innerHTML`. If you need a generic solution, you should provide some more information.

Here is a stackblitz code solving your specific problem (you can open the console to see the log):

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-n47abv?file=index.tsx

Comment: yeah I have to do that, check the structure of the react object and then I write a recursive function to return the props.children if there is typeof string the return it. thanks